# Sybase stored procs using default = Null get scrambled in Python (pyodbc) for INT?

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, sybase, pyodbc

The below stored procedure fails to bind to the defaulted Null parameter when called from pyodbc and does not fetch Null.

```
create procedure test 
  @A INT = Null 
as begin
  select @A, 
  case when @A = Null then 'sybase sees @A as Null' else 'sybase sees @A as *NOT* Null' end,
  Null 
end
```

Calling 'exec test' directly yields:

(null), sybase sees @A as Null, (null).

Whereas calling it via the below

```
sql = 'exec test'
conn = pyodbc.connect(... ANSINULL=off ...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchall()
```

Yields:

> [(-34561235, 'sybase sees @A as Null, -34561235)]

Note, null defaults for char(1), varchar(1) and date yield the expected 'None'

Additional note, since I'm editing a previously asked question that was conflating two issues. Previously I was not adding ANSINULL=off to the connection string, which was yielding:

> [(-34561235, 'sybase sees @A as *NOT* Null, -34561235)]

Additional details as requested in the comments;

SQL_DRIVER_NAME:
Adaptive Server Enterprise (ANSI)

SQL_DRIVER_VER: 15.7.0.104

SELECT @@VERSION:
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 24647 SMP SP134 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp133x/3925/64-bit/FBO/Sat May 2 10:31:07 2015

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/KMBR5YU9) works fine for me on CentOS 7 with the SAP ASE ODBC driver. Please [edit] your question to provide more details about your environment (OS, driver version, etc.).

Comment: What happens if you run it as "exec test @A=NULL"

Comment: Thank-you, I've updated the question as requested @GordThompson

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce your results. Does ANSINULL make any difference if you turn it in or off? Do you get the same results using the `isql` command? (Note: I had to do `SET CHAINED ON` before `exec test` to get the sp to run in isql.) Can you try using the FreeTDS ODBC driver instead of the SAP ASE ODBC driver to see if it behaves differently?

Comment: Note also that `case when @A = Null` really should be `case when @A is null`. Using `=` with NULL can yield unwanted results (although it doesn't seem to matter in this case).

Comment: Sorry @GordThompson, I should have been clearer in my comment. I updated the question with regards to ANSINULL. I was unknowingly conflating two issues. 

Setting this parameter within the connection allows sybase to see that @A is null. However the returned null value (from sybase to Python/Jypyter) is still getting scrambled to a large negative integer. 

I'll see if I can use FreeTDS. Unfortunately company policy might restrict this.

Comment: @GordThompson, I'm still trying to install FreeTDS. However I've found that the Windows version of the Sybase ASE driver shows the correct None/NaN output. I assume that there might be a Linux config setting but I've yet to find it.